# How to send multiple stdin in ansible

Tags: automation, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a bat file like this

```
@echo off
echo please enter Hostname(For Example 127.0.0.1 OR . OR PC-Name)
set /p ServerName="Server Name: "
echo "---------------------ServerName-----------------------------"
echo %ServerName%
echo "-------------------------------------------------"
cls
echo Please Select Authentication Mode:
echo 1- Windows Authentication
echo 2- SQL Server Authentication
set /p AuthMode="Please Enter 1 OR 2: "
```

I use "stdin" within Win_shell but it just gets one input and the ***AuthMode*** is always null

my ansible playbook.yml:

```
 - name: Script
   Win_shell: D:\Myscript.bat
   args:
       stdin: 127.0.0.1
```

is there any solution?

Comment: The [`expect`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html) module should work on windows too.

Comment: Can you show me in code plz?

Answer (score 1):

Try passing a multiline string:

```yaml
- name: Script
  Win_shell: D:\Myscript.bat
  args:
      stdin: |
          127.0.0.1
          2
```

You can check out https://yaml-multiline.info/ for an explanation of how to do multiline strings in yaml (and why the above `|` syntax means "keep newlines and have a single newline at the end").